# Why DataGridView does not show data on 2nd time?

Tags: c#, datagridview

I just need to show updated data in DataGridView. I tried some options but all of them do not work. :-(
Seems that is very tricky control.

Here is the code:

```
    private delegate void displaySearchResultsDgvMethod(DataGridView pDgv, DataTable pTable);
    private void displaySearchResultsDgv(DataGridView pDgv, DataTable pTable)
    {
        if (pDgv.InvokeRequired)
        {
            pDgv.BeginInvoke(new displaySearchResultsDgvMethod(this.displaySearchResultsDgv), pDgv, pTable);
        }
        else
        {
            // Option 1. Smiple direct set
            // pDgv.DataSource = pTable;

            // option 2. update only when different DataTable object
            //bool isDifferent = (pDgv.DataSource == null || !pDgv.DataSource.Equals(pTable));
            //if (isDifferent)
            //    pDgv.DataSource = pTable;

            // option 3. use BindingSource
            if (pTable == null)
            {
                bsOrdersList.DataSource = null;
                bsOrdersList.ResetBindings(true);
            }
            else
            {
                bsOrdersList.DataSource = pTable;
            }
        }
    }

    private bool searchOrders(IProgressor pProgressor, object pState)
    {
        int count = AppDocument.Instance.SearchOrders(this.searchFields, AppDocument.ESearchOptions.EstimateOnly);
        if (count > 1000)
        {
            DialogResult dr = MessageBox.Show(Languages.TranslateFmt("{0} orders found, loading may take time. Do you want to continue?", count),
                Languages.Translate("Confirm"), MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Question, MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button2);
            if (dr == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Cancel) return true;
        }

        /* Option 1-A: reset data before re-loading */ displaySearchResultsDgv(dgvOrdersList, null);
        Thread.Sleep(10);

        AppDocument.Instance.SearchOrders(this.searchFields, (this.joinToLoaded ? AppDocument.ESearchOptions.Join : AppDocument.ESearchOptions.None));
        updateStatusLabs(
            Languages.Translate("Displaying..."),
            Languages.TranslateFmt("+ {0} orders found...", AppDocument.Instance.SearchResults.Rows.Count));

        //displaySearchResults(lvOrdersList);
        displaySearchResultsDgv(dgvOrdersList, AppDocument.Instance.SearchResults);

        return true;
    }
```

With option# 1* it shows data correctly only on 1st search call. On every other attempts to search orders it is always show empty DataGridView despite the fact that data in *AppDocument.Instance.SearchResults* is exists (I see number of rows displayes in UI, also in log file).

With option# 2* it shows the data but it is crashing on attempt to scroll data after 2nd search attempt.

With option# 3 works the same way as option 1.

Notes:

- Type of *AppDocument.Instance.SearchResults* is *DataTable*
- There always will be multiple search attempts but all are loading data into the same instance of *DataTable* object. Sometimes data will be added to *DataTable* object, sometimes data will replace content of *DataTable* object. I need DataGridView to show data correctly in all cases.
- In this particular case set of columns is always the same
- Do not expect to edit data in DataGridView, it should be read-only
- Instance of *DataTable* object which is used here is created manually because there is no db-provider which can work with such data interface.
- I would like not to dispose & re-create instance of *AppDocument.Instance.SearchResults* *DataTable* object. So, it would be nice to re-use the same instance of *DataTable* object. Note: I know that if I will dispose *AppDocument.Instance.SearchResults* *DataTable* object and create new one - this code will work fine but I would like to avoid this.
- It is .NET 3.5

Thank you in advance.

Comment: _I would like not to dispose & re-create instance of AppDocument.Instance.SearchResults DataTable object_ - Why? For me it is more easy way in your case

Comment: There is an option to "join" new search results with existing ones. That is why. So, at least to avoid copying thousands of data rows into new DataTable object on every new orders search.

Comment: In case of "join" another result - just add rows from new datatable to then existing datasource of your datagridview. Because both have same schema it would work

Answer (score 1):

Seems I found very simple solution:

```
    private DataTable dummyTable = new DataTable("DUMMY");

    private bool searchOrders(IProgressor pProgressor, object pState)
    {
        int count = AppDocument.Instance.SearchOrders(this.searchFields, AppDocument.ESearchOptions.EstimateOnly);
        if (count > 1000)
        {
            DialogResult dr = MessageBox.Show(Languages.TranslateFmt("{0} orders found, loading may take time. Do you want to continue?", count),
                Languages.Translate("Confirm"), MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Question, MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button2);
            if (dr == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Cancel) return true;
        }

        displaySearchResultsDgv(dgvOrdersList, this.dummyTable);
        Thread.Sleep(10);

        AppDocument.Instance.SearchOrders(this.searchFields, (this.joinToLoaded ? AppDocument.ESearchOptions.Join : AppDocument.ESearchOptions.None));
        updateStatusLabs(
            Languages.Translate("Displaying..."),
            Languages.TranslateFmt("+ {0} orders found...", AppDocument.Instance.SearchResults.Rows.Count));

        displaySearchResultsDgv(dgvOrdersList, AppDocument.Instance.SearchResults);

        return true;
    }
```

So, just create one additional table - *dummyTable* and then simply switch between these 2 tables - *dummyTable* and * AppDocument.Instance.SearchResult*.

As I can see it works fine. No exceptions. Data displayed correctly.

Comment: Also interesting thing - when DataTable object was cleared with a Clear() method call and then filled with data again then DataGridView may not display any data at all! :-(